# RecyclerView onCreateViewHolder not called

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

RecyclerView setAdapter do but calling method ChatAdapter, registerAdapterDataObserver, onAttachedToRecyclerView, getItemCount 5 calling

xml `layout_height` is `match_parent`

`getItemCount` is `5` not `null`, but `onCreateViewHolder` is not called.

**MyActivity.java:**

```
List<ChatMessage> messages = new ArrayList<ChatMessage>();
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager =  new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());

reyclerview_message_list.setAdapter(new ChatAdapter(messages, R.layout.chat_send));
reyclerview_message_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
reyclerview_message_list.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
reyclerview_message_list.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getApplicationContext(), layoutManager.getOrientation()));
```

**Adapter.java:**

```
public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<ChatMessage> itemList;
private int itemLayout;


public ChatAdapter(List<ChatMessage> items, int itemLayout){
    this.itemList = items;
    this.itemLayout = itemLayout;

}


@Override
public ChatAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View view  = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(itemLayout, viewGroup, false);
    return new ChatAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ChatAdapter.ViewHolder viewholder, int position) {

    ChatMessage item  = itemList.get(position);
    viewholder.messageBody.setText(item.getMessageBody());
    viewholder.messageTime.setText(item.getMessageTime());
    viewholder.messageState.setText(item.getMessageState());
    viewholder.itemView.setTag(item);
}



public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView messageBody, messageTime, messageState;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        messageBody = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_body);
        messageTime= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_time);
        messageState= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_state);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemList.size();
}
```

Why is `onCreateViewHolder` not called?

Comment: Please paste your whole Adapter.java class, this code is not enough.

Comment: sorry i do editing

Comment: @나상혁 did you added value in `messages` and after that called `notifyDataSetChanged()` to that adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I just update your Adapter code and its working well.

```
    public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<ChatMessage> itemList;
    private int itemLayout;
    private Context mContext;

    public ChatAdapter(List<ChatMessage> items, int itemLayout, Context context){
        this.itemList = items;
        this.itemLayout = itemLayout;
        this.mContext = context;
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View view  = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(itemLayout, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewholder, int position) {

        ChatMessage item  = itemList.get(position);
        viewholder.messageBody.setText(item.getMessageBody());
        viewholder.messageTime.setText(item.getMessageTime());
        viewholder.messageState.setText(item.getMessageState());
        viewholder.itemView.setTag(item);
    }



    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView messageBody, messageTime, messageState;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            messageBody = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_body);
            messageTime= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_time);
            messageState= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_state);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }
}
```

And you Activity or Fragment first get the RecyclerView and then set adapter like this:

```
 RecyclerView reyclerview_message_list = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    reyclerview_message_list.setAdapter(new ChatAdapter(messages, R.layout.list_row, this)); // passed another parameter Context
    reyclerview_message_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    reyclerview_message_list.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    reyclerview_message_list.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getApplicationContext(), layoutManager.getOrientation()));
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't notify your adapter after setting the value. While you setting the adapter `messages` is empty. When you adding the value in `messages` using `addAll(message_objects)` those data are added in `ArrayList` but you have to notify the adapter using `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Declare your adapter in class level then create object of adapter before setting the adapter in recyclerview and notify the adapter after you added objects in `ArrayList`.

```
private ChatAdapter chatAdapter;//declare it globally(class level)

chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(messages, R.layout.chat_send);
reyclerview_message_list.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
reyclerview_message_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
reyclerview_message_list.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
reyclerview_message_list.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getApplicationContext(), layoutManager.getOrientation()));
messages.addAll(ChatMessage_Objects_you_getting_from_web_service);
chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```